# Which scripture says the initiation by Saraswathi to Nala on Chintamani mantra?

Tags: scripture, mantras, tantra, saraswati, nala

It is said that Saraswathi initiated the Nala on the Chintamani mantra at the time of Damayanthi swayamvaram.

I heard this from one of the preachings of [H.H Sri Siddheswarananda Bharati Swamy](http://www.siddheswaripeetham.org/peethadhipathi-parampara/h-h-sri-siddheswarananda-bharati-swamy-1937-present-birth-jan-23rd-1937/).

I think H.H Sri Siddheswarananda Bharati Swamy is generally used to deliver preachings based on Tantra scriptures, so there is a chance that the event is mentioned in Tantra scriptures. But I am not sure about this.

Which scripture describes this event of Saraswathi initiating Nala?

Comment: Where was it mentioned so?  The question lacks clarity.  It needs to be closed.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I heard from a Telugu video. Do you want a link?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv The preacher didn't disclose the name of scripture...

Comment: I have also read about this in a book. But I don't think they gave the name of the scripture. @hanugm

Comment: what is chintamani mantra.. ???...

Comment: You can search on Google. You will get some results @HinduKid